# Heavy database load when using CodeIgniter Session class?

Tags: database, session, codeigniter, scalability

After reading about how CodeIgniter handles sessions, it has me concerned about the performance impact when sessions are configured to be stored and retrieved from the database.

This is from the CI documentation: "When session data is available in a database, every time a valid session is found in the user's cookie, a database query is performed to match it."

So every AJAX call, every HTML fragment I request is going to have this overhead? That is potentially a huge issue for systems that are trying to scale!

I would have guessed that CI would have implemented it better: include the MD5 hash to cover both the sessionID+timestamp when encoding them in the session record. Then only check the database for the session record every X minutes whenever the sessionID gets regenerated.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are session headers posted with XmlHttpRequests?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your AJAX requests use a different controller, for example Ajax_Controller instead of MY_Controller. MY_Controller would load the Session class but the Ajax_Controller doesn't. That way when you call to your AJAX, it doesn't touch session data and therefore doesn't make any erroneous calls to the database that aren't necessary.

If you are autoloading the Session class, maybe you can try unloading it for the AJAX requests? I've never tried it but it's talked about here http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/65191/#320552 and then do something like this

if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
// unload session class code goes here
}